# "adire" in indicative present

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'm searching for conjugation of verb "adire" and found different results on different places
http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/Italian/adire.html
Here I found it is

```
io   ado
tu   adi
lui  ade
noi  adiamo
voi  adite
loro adono
```

But on other website http://www.wordreference.com/conj/ITverbs.aspx?v=adire
I found this

```
adisco
adisci
adisce
adiamo
adite
adiscono
```

What of these two is correct?

Comment: I have the feeling that that websites performs automatic translations, meaning it can be wrong (the first is wrong indeed and the second is the right one). It's better to use verified sources: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/adire/

Comment: Thank you for answer @Martina. Also thanks for link it's seems useful.

Comment: Second one is right. First one is not. Entered my 30 characters. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [online Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/adire/) has

> **adire** v. tr. [dal lat. *adire*, comp. di *ad-* e *ire* «andare»] (*io adisco*, *tu adisci*, ecc.). – Propr., andare verso un luogo, ma solo in senso fig., nelle frasi del linguaggio giur.: *a. le vie legali, l’autorità giudiziaria*, *a. il magistrato, il tribunale*, ricorrere alla giustizia, dar corso a un’azione giudiziaria; *a. un’eredità*, accettarla a norma di legge. ◆ Part. pass. **adìto** (con pronuncia piana, diversamente dal lat. *adĭtum*, supino di *adire*), usato con valore verbale in espressioni giuridiche come, in partic., *giudice adito*, al quale si è fatto ricorso, *eredità adita*, accettata.

Several verbs of the third conjugation (*-ire*) use the *-isc-* infix in the singular forms and the third person plural of the present indicative. I don't think *io ado* has ever appeared (the Latin form is *adeo*).

See [this Wikipedia page](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbi_incoativi#Lista_dei_verbi_incoativi) for a list of the verbs that use (or can use) the infix.